# How to deal with AjaxSearch in Modx Evolution and error with htmlspecialchars?

Tags: ajax, search, modx, htmlspecialchars, modx-evolution

I've to make searchbar in MODX and i want to use AjaxSearch which is built in MODX.

I read help about how to set it and I've got page where I've got:

```
    [!AjaxSearch? &showResults=`0` &landingPage=`52` &showMoreResults=`1` &moreResultsPage=`52`!]
```

And on page with `ID=52` I've got:

```
[!AjaxSearch? &showInputForm=`0` &ajaxSearch=`0`!]
```

And where i click search with empty field is ok - I've got alert about it.

But when i type something and search then i've got:

> « MODx Parse Error »
>
> MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
>
> « PHP Parse Error »   PHP error debug
>
> Error:
>
> htmlspecialchars() [function.htmlspecialchars]: charset `ISO-8859-2' not supported, assuming iso-8859-1
>
> Error type/
>   Nr.:  Warning - 2
>
> File:
>
> /home/users/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx/assets/snippets/ajaxSearch/classes/ajaxSearchInput.class.inc.php
>   Line: 340
>   Line 340 source:
>   if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.3', '>=')) $string = htmlspecialchars($string, $quote_style, $charset, $double_encode);

How can i deal with it? How can i repair this?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wiki you may need change the TinyMCE configuration to raw:

Searching for words containing characters like "å,ä,ö,Å,Ä,Ö" require to configure your editor to avoid entity encoding. With TinyMCE, for that, change the entity_encoding parameter from "named" to "raw" in the configuration tab and save again your documents.

Also here is a thread from the forums with a similar situation. 
http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=26336.ne&i=1&page=2

Comment: I change charset in file from my question and i can search now. But the problem is when i try to click in searched link from results. can you check it in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840969/how-to-repair-this-issue-when-i-click-on-result-link-in-modx-ajaxsearch