# How to repair this issue when i click on result link in modx ajaxSearch?

Tags: search, character-encoding, modx

I used ajaxSearch on this site: `http://www.rhemapress.pl/www_poradnia/` and when I type something, e.g: `czwarta` or `wspomaganie` then when i clicked on one of return links then it redirect me to this document but on end of this link is something like this:
`&searched=wspomaganie&advsearch=oneword&highlight=ajaxSearch_highlight+ajaxSearch_highlight1` and i've got this error after I clicked.

```
  MODx encountered the following error while attempting to parse the requested resource:
  htmlentities() [function.htmlentities]: charset `ISO-8859-2' not supported, assuming iso-8859-1
  /home/users/rhemapress/public_html/rhemapress/www_poradnia/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php(790) : eval()'d code
```

Where is the problem? How can i do this correctly? Database is UTF8.

Comment: Is in MODX something like: "Index your all pages"? Or "Refresh paths"? Maybe here is the problem? On other modx install this works correctly.

Comment: What is the character set of the page(s)? I am not sure if this would matter since it's ajax.  Do you have the meta tag:  <meta charset="utf-8"> in the head of each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace the character set similar to how they do it here:

http://forums.modx.com/index.php?topic=17161.0

Find instances similar to this, specifically the "etomite_charset":

```
 htmlentities($output,ENT_QUOTES,$modx->config['etomite_charset']);
```

Replace with something similar to this:

```
 htmlentities($output, ENT_QUOTES);
```

However I don't know all the instance of where this would appear in the ajax search plugin.